# Error on getting corresponding dateTime of max value

Tags: mysql, sql

**Table 'test'**

```
+------+--------------------+
|value |    dateTime        |
+------+--------------------+
|19    |2011-12-22 11:09:42 |
+------+--------------------+
|16    |2011-12-22 05:09:00 |
+------+--------------------+
|2     |2011-12-22 07:09:42 |
+------+--------------------+
|30    |2011-12-22 10:09:15 |
+------+--------------------+
|45    |2011-12-22 03:09:42 |
+------+--------------------+
```

I would like to get the Max value and its corresponding dateTime. In this case, the final result should be: **max value:45 and dateTime:2011-12-22 03:09:42**. I used

```
SELECT MAX( `value` ) , `dateTime`
FROM `test`
```

After running the above sql statement, the max 'value' is correct (i.e. 45), but the **'dateTime 'is not correct (i.e.2011-12-22 11:09:19)**

Is there anyone can help me? Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 `value`, `dateTime`
FROM `test`
ORDER BY `value` DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

```
-- general
select *
from test
where value= (select max(value) from test)
```

or

```
--tsql
select top 1 *
from test
order by value desc
```

or

```
--mysql
select *
from test
order by value desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: The OP is looking for max value, not max datetime :)

Comment: @Andomar No, the OP is looking for max value and the corresponding datetime, so the query should produce the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in MySQL in version 5.5.  Try upgrading MySQL.  Your code is not the problem.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=54784